# python - django error "RuntimeError: doesn't declare an explicit app_label"

Tags: python, django

I am struggling with a problem in using django. When I type `python manage.py runserver`, it holds for few seconds and keeps giving me a following message:

> RuntimeError: Model class upload.models.ImgParent doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.

I searched similar problems on the internet and tried to add `'upload.models.ImgParent'` on `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py` but it still doesn't work.

My current `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py` looks like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [

    'search.apps.SearchConfig',
    'upload.apps.UploadConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_extensions',
    'mod_wsgi.server',
    'home',
]
```

and my apps.py looks like this:

```
class UploadConfig(AppConfig):

    name = 'upload'
```

edit, this is full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/edwardkim/syseng/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/edwardkim/syseng/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/home/edwardkim/syseng/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 77, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[0](_exception[1]).with_traceback(_exception[2])
  File "/home/edwardkim/syseng/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/edwardkim/syseng/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/edwardkim/syseng/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/edwardkim/syseng/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 134, in create
    % (mod_path, cls_name, ', '.join(candidates))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'upload.apps' does not contain a class 'uploadConfig'. Choices are: 'UploadConfig'.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 19, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/edwardkim/syseng/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/edwardkim/syseng/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/edwardkim/syseng/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/edwardkim/syseng/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 60, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/home/edwardkim/syseng/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/edwardkim/syseng/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 95, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "/home/edwardkim/syseng/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 102, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "/home/edwardkim/syseng/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 579, in run_with_reloader
    start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/edwardkim/syseng/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 564, in start_django
    reloader.run(django_main_thread)
  File "/home/edwardkim/syseng/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 272, in run
    get_resolver().urlconf_module
  File "/home/edwardkim/syseng/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/edwardkim/syseng/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 564, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/home/edwardkim/syseng/venv/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/edwardkim/syseng/Foram_Tagger_Team43_Software/projectsite/projectsite/urls.py", line 23, in <module>
    path('search/', include('search.urls')),
  File "/home/edwardkim/syseng/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/home/edwardkim/syseng/venv/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/edwardkim/syseng/Foram_Tagger_Team43_Software/projectsite/search/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/home/edwardkim/syseng/Foram_Tagger_Team43_Software/projectsite/search/views.py", line 2, in <module>
    from upload.models import Img
  File "/home/edwardkim/syseng/Foram_Tagger_Team43_Software/projectsite/upload/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    class ImgParent(models.Model):
  File "/home/edwardkim/syseng/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 111, in __new__
    "INSTALLED_APPS." % (module, name)
RuntimeError: Model class upload.models.ImgParent doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

Please help with my problem and let me know if you need any additional information. Thank you.

Comment: Please show the full traceback. Don't add `'upload.models.ImgParent'` to `INSTALLED_APPS` - `'upload.apps.UploadConfig'` looks correct, so the problem might be somewhere else.

Comment: @Alasdair Thank you for reply, I just edited and posted the full traceback.

Comment: `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'upload.apps' does not contain a class 'uploadConfig'. Choices are: 'UploadConfig'.` - that suggests you have `'upload.apps.uploadConfig'` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`. If you definitely have `'upload.apps.UploadConfig'`, then make sure you have saved/committed your changes, and restarted the server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I pulled the whole project from git and originally there was 'upload.apps.UploadConfig' and i just checked it again in apps.py as well. Could there be another solution for the problem?

Comment: If the error contains `uploadConfig`, then either you have `uploadConfig` in your code you are running, or you had it in your code and haven’t restarted the server since then. I can’t think of any other way that `uploadConfig` would appear in the error message.